# How can I get all multiples of 3 in range 50 using clojure.core.logic?

Tags: clojure, logic, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to understand `core.logic` and running up against a wall of sparse-documentation, and out-dated tutorials.

If I can make decent progress with the lib, I want to document some things and help the community, but so far, it's rough going...

My current problem is basically "fizzbuzz", as I'm trying to learn clojure against doing Project Euler problems.

A simple piece of the puzzle is simply getting all multiples of 3 in the range of 50, but the following throws an error:

```
(run* [q]
  (membero q (range 50))
  (conde
   [(== (mod q 3) 0)]))

=> clojure.core.logic.LVar cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

Any thoughts? Also, any references to learning more of `core.logic`? Is `core.logic` still "a thing", or is stagnating as it's git repo would suggest?

Comment: There is an example using mod in `clojure.core.logic.tests`

Comment: @Andre thanks! I just used that to write the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@Andre's comment solved it for me:
https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/f3f2b4c6c4a906c1fa512720aa09cb1abe312cd1/src/test/clojure/clojure/core/logic/tests.clj#L1242

```
(defnc dev3c [x]
  (zero? (mod x 3)))

(run* [x]
  (membero x (range 50))
  (dev3c x))
```